# Grails overloaded controller workaround

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading, grails

I had an overloaded method, but Grails doesn't allow overloaded methods in controller actions.  The overloaded method looked like this:

```
def punch(User user, User source) {
    user.userVersion++
    punch(user, source, null, null)
  }


 def punch(User user, User source, String latitude, String longitude) {

     UserPunch userPunch = new UserPunch()
     userPunch.punchClockStatus = user.punchClockStatus
     userPunch.user = user
     userPunch.job = user.job
     userPunch.task = user.task
     userPunch.date = new Date()
     userPunch.source = source
     userPunch.save(flush: true)
     if (latitude != null) {
        userPunch.latitude = latitude
        userPunch.longitude = longitude
     }
     if (userPunch.hasErrors())
        userPunch.errors.each {
            log.error it
     }
}
```

In order to get around the restrictions on overloaded methods, I used a try/catch, like this:

```
def punch(User user, User source, String latitude, String longitude) {

    UserPunch userPunch = new UserPunch()
    userPunch.punchClockStatus = user.punchClockStatus
    userPunch.user = user
    userPunch.job = user.job
    userPunch.task = user.task
    userPunch.date = new Date()
    userPunch.source = source
    userPunch.save(flush: true)
    try {
        userPunch.latitude = latitude
        userPunch.longitude = longitude
    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        user.userVersion++
    }
    if (userPunch.hasErrors())
        userPunch.errors.each {
            log.error it
        }
}
```

Does this look like it will work right? Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Shouldn't this also be tagged with the "Groovy" tag?

Comment: Why are you asking if it will work right? Have you tried?

Comment: I'm upgrading someone else's code from Grails 1.7 to Grails 2.3.4, so it has multiple compiler errors. I haven't even gotten it to run yet. This was one of them that I'm hoping I fixed, but just because it cleared the compiler error doesn't mean it will work correctly in runtime. I can't do unit testing until I fix all the other compiler errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you use default parameters, you won't need to overload the function.

```
def punch(User user, User source, String latitude=null, String longitude=null)
```

Comment: Default parameter values are not allowed in controller methods, same as overloading.

Answer (score 2):

Controller actions may not be overloaded but non-action methods can be. So you can do something like this to keep the code as similar to the original as possible:

```
def punch(User user, User source, String latitude, String longitude) {
    if (latitude != null) punchImpl(user, source, latitude, longitude)
    else punchImpl(user, source)
}

protected punchImpl(user, source) {
    ...
}

protected punchImpl(user, source, latitude, longitude) {
    ...
}
```

Then you may as well think about putting the punch method overloads inside a service since controllers shouldn't contain "business" logic anyway.